# Spring MVC: Refusing matched mapping

Tags: spring, spring-mvc

Consider a situation where we can have several mappings with the same regular expression, which should be validated programmatically (for instance against database).

(this is not a valid piece of code, I am trying just to explain what I am trying to achieve. Note the regular expressions in the url path)

```
// Animal controller
@GetMapping(path = "/{animal-category [a-z-]+}/{animal-name [a-z-]+}")
public void show(@PathVariable String animalCategory, @PathVariable String animalName) {
    // if animalCategory is not found in database, continue with next controller
}

// Plants controller
@GetMapping(path = "/{plant-category [a-z-]+}/{plant-name [a-z-]+}")
public void show(@PathVariable String plantCategory, @PathVariable String plantName) {
    // if plantCateogry is not found in database, continue with next controller - as there is no more, it should return 404
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve this problem with a general controller method like this:

```
// General controller method
@GetMapping(path = "/{category [a-z-]+}/{name [a-z-]+}")
public void show(@PathVariable String category, @PathVariable String name) {

    // look in database for the category

    if(isAnimalCatagory) {

        return showAnimal(category, name);
    } 
    else if(isPlantCategory) }

        return showPlant(category, name);
    }

    return "redirect:/404";
}

public void showAnimal(String animalCategory, String animalName) {
    // for animal categories
}

public void showPlant(String plantCategory, String plantName) {
    // for plant categories
}
```

Comment: The problem is that there might be some other controllers with the same regex. In fact this was a simplification of our current state – I would like to be able to "post process" what was matched. I know it could be solved by your technique but then it becomes not exactly clean and nice.